# Почему не работает дебаг angular-приложения?

Tags: intellij-idea, angular2, отладка, typescript, angular4

Выбираю JavaScript Debug, пишу локальный url: https://test-app.lan:3009
В списке Remote URLs of local, нахожу корневую папку приложения (там и node_modules лежит), указываю ей так же URL: https://test-app.lan:3009

В итоге, консоль в дебаггере видно, бряки (breakpoints) галочкой помечаются как рабочие когда модуль приложения загружается, но он не останавливается на них. Фактически ни одна бряка не работает.

У меня версия idea - 2017.3, angular 5.x, typescript 2.6. На остальных проектах (которые не angular, но написаны на typescript) таких проблем нет.
В чем может быть проблема? Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

p.s. сначала я подумал что дело может быть в lazyload модулей - но нет, главный модуль (app.module) тоже не дебажится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Независимо от используемой IDE Вы всеравно используете angular-cli.
Рекомендую **отладку через chrome dev tools**:

1) запускаете приложение через  `ng serve`

2) Sources -> webpack://./src/app/.. ваши .ts файлы

3) ставите breakpoint (отмечен синим на строке 9)

4) F5, взаимодействие с приложением, пока не попадете в код где проверяется breakpoint

Подробнее - видно на скриншоте ниже:

[image: отладка в chrome]